# Different RequestMapping value within same Controller

Tags: spring, rest

There is an existing Controller that I want to add an additional get Method with a slightly modified logic. There is the `findAll` method and I want to add the `getMessages` method.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/options", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
public class OptionController {

 ...Definitions etc...

 @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<?> findAll(@PageableDefault(size = Integer.MAX_VALUE) Pageable pageable) {
        Page<Option> page = optionRepository.findAll(pageable);
        return ok(pagingAssembler.toResource(page));
    }
}
```

And below the new method:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/optionsWelcome", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ResponseEntity<?> getMessages(@PageableDefault(size = Integer.MAX_VALUE) Pageable pageable) {
    Page<Option> page = optionRepository.findAll(pageable);
    return ok(pagingAssembler.toResource(page));
}
```

I am getting 404 for http calls to `/optionsWelcome` but `/options` works.

Is it possible to have a controller with mappings for 2 different URLs or do I need to make a second controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/options` is the mapping for the entire controller. `/options/optionsWelcome` will probably work.

You need to move `/options` mapping to the method.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, your 100% correct. Waiting for time limit to accept your answer!